# Defining a string from another string, an int and a string literal

Tags: c++, string

First off, the function in question.

```
bool Animation::loadFrames()
{
        sf::Texture frame[frameCount];
        std::string pathToFrame;
        for(int i = 1; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
            pathToFrame = pathToAnimation + i + ".jpg";
            if(!frame[i].loadFromFile(pathToFrame)) return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

The line that's giving me trouble is

```
pathToFrame = pathToAnimation + i + ".jpg";
```

pathToAnimation is another std::string, frameCount is an int. I want to somehow make one string that looks like: "./Assets/Sprites/Player/Stand/1.jpg"

I know why my code doesn't work, I just don't know what the correct code would be.

Comment: I'm not saying there is only one way to do it, but often times sprite animations are loaded from a single sprite sheet. http://ken-soft.com/2009/01/02/sprite-class-in-c-using-sdl/

Comment: So for example, `spriteWidth = imageWidth / frames;`, then you just blit the current frame (the animation).

Comment: The reason I'm not using a sprite sheet is because these are isometric sprites and so have 8 directions for every frame of every animation for the sprite. The resulting sheets would be huge, and so it's easier to organize them into files and folders and then load them separately.

Comment: Given a player that can move in 8 directions, and hence the animations are likely to change often you are still going to have to load all the animations into memory either way. So I don't fully see the advantage of breaking it up file by file. It's faster/easier to load one sprite and read from it than to load many sprites and have to manage them.

Comment: Though I guess it doesn't really matter that much If you have tools to easily manage all the animations. But most tile/map/animation editors I have worked with for gaming deal with sprite sheets and not individual tiles, hence my feedback. (I say this because my very first tile base games I developed, I did the same thing as you but had many headaches dealing with all the individual tiles.)

Comment: It's easier for me to make the sprites individual images so I don't have to make a huge sprite sheet and I don't have to worry about where to move to get the proper frame. If I didn't have around 60 frames per animation I would make a sprite sheet. But 60 frames in 8 directions for 6-10 animations per sprite is way too much for me to handle. I simply feel this is the best way to do it for this particular project.

Comment: I should note, this is an RTS so the amount of animations and sprites are pretty huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Joachim's answer, you may also use C++11's new `to_string` functions to convert an `int` into a `std::string`

```
pathToFrame = pathToAnimation + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Best solution, and allows me to remove the pathToFrame variable altogether and just do

`if(!frame[i].loadFromFile(pathToAnimation + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg")) return false;`

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << pathToAnimation << 123 << ".jpg"

std::cout << ostr.str();
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides using [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), C++11 provides [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) with overloads for integral anf floating point types. With `std::to_string`:

```
pathToFrame = pathToAnimation + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
```

with `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << pathToAnomation << i << ".jpg";
pathToFrame = os.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/) you could write:

```
pathToFrame = (boost::format("%1%%2%.jpg") % pathToAnimation % i).str();
```

With [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) you can also write

```
pathToFrame = pathToAnimation + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i) + ".jpg";
```